# Надо ли выделить "для ознакомления" запятыми?

Tags: запятые

Уважаемые коллеги, направляю вам для ознакомления утвержденный план работ.

Answer (score 2):

*Уважаемые коллеги, направляю вам для ознакомления утвержденный план работ.*

Грамматика предложения не требует обособления, это не оборот, в официальном документе запятые не нужны, но если это, например, сопроводительная записка частного характера, можно обособить как пояснение, но это будет авторская пунктуация.